# Display UIView while waiting for main view to load?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview, xib

So I am trying to create somewhat of a loading screen in my application. I have a view that takes 3-10 seconds to load. During this time I want to display a UIView that I made that is simply black with a loading screen. Currently I am putting my code inside of the viewDidLoad function just after super viewDidLoad. Here is my code

```
UIView* baseView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
[self.view addSubview:baseView];
[baseView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:baseView];
baseView.layer.zPosition = 1;
```

This works and creates my view overtop of everything exactly how I want it, however this waits until my main view is completely done loading before it actually shows anything. Is viewDidLoad not a good place to put this and if so where should I put it.

Simply put I have a very basic UIView that I want to load while I wait for the actual view to load and then simply hide it. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Why your view takes 3-10 seconds to load?

Comment: Where are you running the code that is taking the time?  it sounds like you need to dispatch it asynchronously

Comment: The view takes so long to load because it has to download a lot of content,    I am working on making everything asynchronous however this is more of a temporary fix as I will not be able to make it asynchronous for about a month.

Comment: Until you can move the loading onto a background thread you will block the UI update.  It shouldn't take you a month to do this.  All you need to do is wrap a `dispatch_async` around the code and have it invoke a method once it is done.

Comment: Well its not that simple, I have several functions that cause the loading that are quite complex. Its not as simple as just wrapping it in a dispatch_async, In addition to this I have other things that need to be done first hence the temporary fix. This will also serve as a nice loader for even 300ms-1second delays on normal views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to dispatch your hard work on another thread, otherwise the OS will wait until all the process is done before refreshing the UI (that's why you see your loading screen appear only after 3-10 seconds).

Don't forget to dispatch back on the main thread after the lengthy job is done.  All UI updates must be done on the main thread.

```
self.loadingView.hidden = NO;
// Dispatch lengthy stuff on another thread
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    // Do lengthy stuff here

    // Dispatch back on the main thread (mandatory for UI updates)
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.loadingView.hidden = YES;
    });
});
```

Comment: Or if you *really* wants your lengthy job being performed on the main thread, I think you can use a ```[self performSelector:@selector(lengthyJobMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:0]``` to allow your loading view the time to be displayed, but I highly recommend moving your stuff inside a ```dispatch_async```.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIView* baseView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
[self.view addSubview:baseView];
[baseView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:baseView];
baseView.layer.zPosition = 1; 

//Create new dispatch for load data
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    // Load data in here

    // Call main thread to update UI
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        baseView.hidden = YES;
    });
});
```